# How can I add N milliseconds to a datetime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm setting a datetime var as such:

```
fulldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

where date and time are string of the appropriate nature for datetime.  How can I increment this datetime by N milliseconds?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `timedelta`

To increment by 500 ms:

```
fulldate = datetime.datetime.strptime(date + ' ' + time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
fulldate = fulldate + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=500)
```

You can use it to increment minutes, hours, days etc. Documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Answer (score 9):

use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta.tzinfo):

```
timedelta(microseconds=1000) #1 milli second
```