# Increasing a timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, epoch

I got a starting timestamp of *14813.501476* which translated to epoch unix time is *GMT: Thursday, January 1, 1970 4:06:53.501 AM*. I got a duration in ms which is *539,161999999124* or about half a second.

Now I wanted to find out what the time is when adding this half a second to the timestamp, like this:

*14813.501476* + *539.161999999124*

but it adds up to *15377.599602999124* or *GMT: Thursday, January 1, 1970 4:16:17.599 AM*
which is mere 10 minutes to much.

I'm obviously messing up the decimal here but I seem too be to stupid to figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried `timedelta` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522827/4636715)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
14813.501476 + (539.161999999124/ 1000)
```

See [Pyfiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/2e60fca5-ce8c-475d-8615-cb73c5c0b0de)

The duration has miliseconds units and the timestamp has seconds units.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I actually did try this but when I checked the time, it was still wrong so that is why I asked! Now I tried it again and this time it looked correct.